# TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable and pygame window crashes

Tags: python, crash, pygame

I'm quite new to Pygame and Python and I've just made one of my first codes but somehow I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable
```

I don't know whether there is something wrong in the code or just because Pygame/Python isn't installed correctly.

```
bif="bg.jpg"
mif="ball.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

screen.blit(background, (0,0))

x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
x -= mouse_c.get_width()/2
y -= mouse_c.get_height()/2

screen.blit(mouse_c(x,y))

pygame.display.update()
```

After running this code the pygame window crashes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ``pygame``, but the error is pretty self explanatory. Somewhere in your code you are getting an object of type ``pygame.Surface``, and then you are attempting to call it (use the ``()`` operator). My guess is that something you think is a method is actually just an attribute value and thus doesn't need the ``()``.

Comment: Could you please provide the full traceback?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dhti/Desktop/gamez/game.py", line 27, in <module>
    screen.blit(mouse_c(x,y))
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable` @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
screen.blit(mouse_c(x,y))
```

should be

```
screen.blit(mouse_c, (x,y))
                 # ^
```

In the first version, `mouse_c(x, y)` is interpreted as an attempt to *call* `mouse_c` (which is a `pygame.Surface` and thus not callable) with arguments `x` and `y`, when they are in fact separate arguments (`source` and `dest`) to [`screen.blit`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit).